# Input to assign value to double variable

Tags: java

I'm trying to get it where the user inputs a 1 or 2 for a predetermined values. Then using that to calculate a final cost.

Example:
Would you like the red or orange box? 1 for red, 2 for orange

The red would cost $10 and the orange $12.

How do I connect the inputs 1 and 2 to $10 and $12? Do I use switch or if?

Comment: Both will work. Usually for situations like this (menu options) `switch` is preferred but it really doesn't make a difference in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Both options work. I personally prefer using the `switch` statement as it makes the code a bit more readable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Untitled {


    public static void main (String[]args) {

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        // this is where you store your items - you would obviously have to create the class and its methods first
        // ArrayList <Item> items = new ArrayList<>;
        // items.Add(new Item(SomePrice, SomeName);

        System.out.println("Item 1 or 2");
        String input = s.nextLine();

        // Option 1
        switch(input) {
            case ("1"): {
                System.out.println("Cost is 1");
                // some method to retreive an item from the list of Items carrying the name one
                // get user Input
                // update the item in the list
                break;
            }
            case ("2"):{
                System.out.println("Cost is 2");
                break;
            }
        }


        // Option 2
        if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
            System.out.println("Cost is 1");
        else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
            System.out.println("Cost is 2");

    }

}
```

Comment: Is it possible to assign a value to a variable in each case?

Comment: I don't quite get your question but you could create an `ArrayList<Items>` and then call a method on an Item of that list to get the price. I have extended the code to give you some hints.